# How can I check if a point(Vector3) is in Matrix4x4

Tags: unity

I'm placing random objects in an imaginary cube in front of my target. I am using following code to do this:

```
var center = Vector3.zero;
center.z = (m_size.z / 2) + m_offset.z;
center.x += m_offset.x;
center.y += m_offset.y;
var mat = Matrix4x4.TRS(m_target.position, m_target.rotation, m_target.lossyScale);
Vector3 pos = center + new Vector3(Random.Range(-m_size.x / 2, m_size.x / 2), Random.Range(-m_size.y / 2, m_size.y / 2), Random.Range(-m_size.z / 2, m_size.z / 2));
pos = mat.MultiplyPoint(pos);
m_instantiatedObject.Add(Instantiate(m_object, pos, Quaternion.identity));
```

And it's working as expected. but now my problem is as my target moves, the previously placed objects may not be in this imaginary cube anymore. how can I check if my placed objects are in this imaginary cube and if they are not I can remove them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was able to get it to work. This is the code that worked for me:

```
Bounds b = new Bounds(center, m_size);
for(int i= m_instantiatedObject.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
        if(!b.Contains(rot.inverse.MultiplyPoint3x4(m_instantiatedObject[i].transform.position)))
        {
                var item = m_instantiatedObject[i];
                m_instantiatedObject.RemoveAt(i);
                Destroy(item);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you can try something like this:

```
// foreach object get the relative posizion from target
vector3 relPos = m_object.position - m_target.position
if (Mathf.Abs(relPos.x) > m_size.x / 2) || 
   (Mathf.Abs(relPos.y) > m_size.y / 2) || 
   (Mathf.Abs(relPos.z) > m_size.z / 2) 
{
 // object is outside the target cube
}
```